# How can i count the days within/without sales in a period

Tags: mdx

How can i count the days within/without sales in a period.

I defined a MDX query below:

```
SELECT { [Measures].[Sales], [Measures].[Amount] } ON COLUMNS
NONEMPTY({ [Dim Customer].[Customer ID].[Customer ID].ALLMEMBERS * 
           [Time].[Month].CHILDREN
}) DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube]
```

The result shows me for each customer and month how many sales and amount the customer had in the corresponding month.

```
CustomID / Month / Sales / Amount:
1 / 2013 01 / 123 / 2234:
1 / 2013 02 / 2 / 95:
1 / 2013 03 / 212 / 11111:
2 / 2013 01 / 122 / 2121:
2 / 2013 02 / 231 / 3333:
```

Now I need a counter/column which shows me the value of days in the month without sales.

```
CustomID / Month / Sales / Amount / DaysNoSale:
1 / 2013 01 / 123 / 2234 / 3:
1 / 2013 02 / 2 / 95 / 26:
1 / 2013 03 / 212 / 11111 / 0:
2 / 2013 01 / 122 / 2121 / 0:
2 / 2013 02 / 231 / 3333 / 0:
```

In cube we have the details for every day so it´s possible to show the number of sales per day. 
On days witout sales this number is 0.

Has anybody an idea how i can solve this rquest.
Thanks forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Day attribute is named `[Time].[Day]`, you would use:

```
WITH Member Measures.[Days No Sale] AS
     Filter([Time].[Day].[Day].Members * { [Time].[Month].CurrentMember },
            ([Measures].[Sales], [Dim Customer].[Customer ID].CurrentMember) = 0
           ).Count
SELECT { [Measures].[Sales], [Measures].[Amount], Measures.[Days No Sale] }
       ON COLUMNS,
       NONEMPTY({ [Dim Customer].[Customer ID].[Customer ID].ALLMEMBERS * 
                [Time].[Month].CHILDREN
               })
       DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
       ON ROWS
  FROM [MyCube]
```

`[Time].[Day].[Day].Members * { [Time].[Month].CurrentMember }` is the cross product of all days in the cube with the current month of the row. And due to the Analysis Services Autoexists feature, this only returns non empty tuples, i. e. one tuple for each day in the month, as e. g. there is no record in the time dimension table containing September, 10, 2014 in the day column and July 2013 in the month column. I. e. the cross product within a dimension is not a real cross product in Analysis Services.

Then the `Filter` method restricts these to those having no sales for the current customer id, and finally the `Count` just counts these.